# Map with Leaflet and ReaMap with Leaflet and React does not update when country changes

Tags: reactjs, openstreetmap, react-leaflet

I have a problem when I select another country and the map doesn't update with the new coordinates being passed to the Map component.

Map Component:

```
export const Map = ({lat,lng}) => {

 
    return (
      <>
        <MapContainer
          center={[lat, lng]}
          zoom={4}
          scrollWheelZoom={false}
          className='map-leaflet' 
        >
          <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
        </MapContainer>
      </>
    );
}
```

If I use console.log I see the new coordinates but the map doesn't update.

CodeSandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/pierre1590/Population-Tracker/draft/gallant-gagarin?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FMap%2FMap.js

Comment: sounds like the map component not re-render. try to make ur coordinates var as a state.

Comment: give more code like where you use this map component so we can provide more help

Comment: I have no permission to access

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/pierre1590/Population-Tracker/draft/gallant-gagarin?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FMap%2FMap.js

Comment: still have no permission. but I think @Fawad Shah 's answer  should  be good enough, i properly will do the same. `key` or `state` are the two most important thing to trigger re-render